# Retrieve an object from a two dimensional array matching a specific parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, object

So I have a 2d array containing multiple objects. Each object has multiple properties and methods. I would like to return only the objects methods and properties that have a matching id to what I pass it. in this case, the id is 1.

```js
const blogData = [
    {
        title : "Title 1",
        date : "2017-07-15",
        id : 1
    },
    {
        title : "Title 2",
        data : "2017-07-16",
        id : 2
    }
];

for (let i = 0; i < blogData.length; i++) {
  if (blogData[i].id === 1) {
      console.log(`Post #${blogData[i].id} loaded`);
  }                        
}
```

Comment: `blogData` is not a multi demential array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the array based on ID, and assuming you just have one hit, you can return the first *(and only)* item, or skip `shift()` and get an array of matches.

```js
const blogData = [{
    title: "Title 1",
    date: "2017-07-15",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Title 2",
    data: "2017-07-16",
    id: 2
  }
];

var result = blogData.filter( x => x.id === 1).shift();

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic function that will work with any `ID` and any list.
Something like:

```js
    const blogData = [
        {
            title : "Title 1",
            date : "2017-07-15",
            id : 1
        },
        {
            title : "Title 2",
            data : "2017-07-16",
            id : 2
        }
    ];
    
    function getData(id, arr, callback){
       $.each(arr, function(key, value){
         if(value.id === id)
           callback(value); //Just using a simple callback for console purposes
          });
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
     getData(1, blogData, function(c){
        console.log(c); //loggin the callback
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case this is an `array` of objects and not a 2 dimentional array, so you can use [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter only the `object` that has the `id=1`:

```
var res = blogData.filter(function(obj){
  return obj.id === searchedId;
}).shift();
```

**Demo:**

```js
const blogData = [
    {
        title : "Title 1",
        date : "2017-07-15",
        id : 1
    },
    {
        title : "Title 2",
        data : "2017-07-16",
        id : 2
    }
];

var searchedId = 1;

var res = blogData.filter(function(obj){
  return obj.id === searchedId;
}).shift();
console.log(res);
```

And using your method with `foor` loop, you just need to return the right `object` if the condition is matched:

```
var result = {};
for (let i = 0; i < blogData.length; i++) {
  if (blogData[i].id === 1) {
      result = blogData[i]
  }                        
}
```